# Any harm to the monitor in using SendMessage Function

Tags: vb.net, sendmessage

I developed a little app which uses `SendMessage` function to turn off monitor. My friend asked me whether using the app regularly will harm his monitor. He had some issues with his mother board when he used a similar app. Is there any harm (for hardware) in using the function to do things like these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not unless the monitor is faulty.

That said, turning it on and off very fast might stress it eventually.  I'd consider enforcing a minimum of a couple of seconds between each turn on.